# Let $S$ be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Prove the following are equivalent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

[image]

I have no idea how to show these are equivalent. Can someone help me break this down step-by-step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the following two statements are equivalent:

1. For all $\epsilon>0$ there exists some $s \in S$ such that $0 < |s-x| < \epsilon$.
2. For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists some $s \in S$ such that $0 < |s-x| < {1 \over n}$.

Also, $|s_n-x| \to 0$ **iff** $s_n \to x$.

Comment: Could you elaborate why $f(s)=|x−s|$? I'm having trouble following your work.

Comment: My main point is that the for all $\epsilon>0$ statement (which is the limit point definition) is equivalent to the second bullet point above. Let me simplify the above a bit.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: Take $\epsilon = \dfrac{1}{n} > 0, \exists s_n \in S\setminus \{x\}: |s_n - x| < \dfrac{1}{n}$